# Wrong width of page unecessary scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with this layout, everything looks good, however the page goes further right with nothing but blank. I tried everything nothing works.

```
.container.open-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  left: 240px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container open-sidebar">
  <div id="sidebar">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what forces the problem. Thats the first div and then everything shifts from the left which makes a blank space on the right.

How do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: I think we'll need to see your HTML and likely the rest of your CSS

Comment: Post minimum possible code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please post your code! And by the way, `left` is ignored on relative layout.

Comment: ok i posted the main code. I'm a backend developer so i really struggle with layouts. Please be kind

Comment: @Aloso That is incorrect.  You might be thinking of static layouts.  For relative, it adjusts the element relative to its original position and flow.

Comment: I've made some changes to the original code just trying to figure it out so there might be some dumb statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule that you are using

```
.container.open-sidebar {
  position:relative;
  left: 240px;
}
```

moves that DIV 240px to the right, but there it still a width of 100%, so it will extend the width of the parent container on the right side by 240px.

If you add `width: calc(100% - 240px);`, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Ok we're getting somewhere! The blank space and scroll is gone but my sidebar is cut in half.

Comment: Ok i fixed it with
     width: calc(100% - 480px);

Thanks man!:)